# Android and IOS game engine

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, cross-platform

I'm looking for a 2D game engine to use to target both Android and IOS without the need to rewrite my code. Bonus points if WP7 is supported too.

I found many of them, but they all uses c++. I would really like a game engine that uses an interpreted/high level language(c#, java, python, lua, you say. My preference is toward strong typed ones), productivity with this languages is far better than with C/C++(at least on my side)

I found this ones:

[Emo framework](http://www.emo-framework.com/faq.html)

pros:

- BSD licence
- Uses interpreted language ([Squirrel](http://www.squirrel-lang.org/), ps: never heard of it, but it seams good)

cons:

- Really simple Api
- No access to full features of the underlying system (no way to connect with bluetooth or internet using the os api)

[Mono](http://xamarin.com/monotouch)

pros:

- C#
- WP7 support, + other
- it seams very well supported

cons:

- both mono for android and mono for ios are 400$ each. I'm a student and i develop in free time, i have no such money to invest, and if i must chose between the 2, i'll chose android and stick with AndEngine, that is really good for my needs right now(too sad it is Android only)

Well, i don't know other engines that work on both platforms and use an interpreted language.

About C++ ones,

[cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/)

- open source
- C++
- well documented? (since it is a porting from cocos2d, i expect the tutorials for cocos2d to be useful to cocos2d-x too)
- WP7 possible porting
- it doesn't ease developing for both platform from only pc (obviously a mac is needed in any case to load the app to the store)

[Marmalade](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/marmalade)

- C++
- reasonable price (149$ [with in-app splash](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxwdyOGXqPc). +300$ just to remove it is a bit too much)
- [Apps program](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/apps-program)
- [Very well support for running it in the emulator](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/mobile-development/how-we-built-an-ios-game-on-pc-r2880) (paragraph: Technology)
- [Good help in deploying the app](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/mobile-development/how-we-built-an-ios-game-on-pc-r2880) (paragraph: Getting it on a Device)

Have i missed some good one? I really would like to find a good one that uses an interpreted language, but the one i found is too much expensive or doesn't fulfil my needs(i need to fully access the networking apis). If such an engine doesn't exists, i think i'll use cocos2d-x (since it is open source), but i'm sure i haven't taken into consideration other engines!

Answer (score 5):

There are many game engines that work for both Android and iOS, 26 by my last count. Take a look at http://mobilegameengines.com/

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Unity](http://unity3d.com).

For 2D games you don't need the Pro version of it, though the non-Pro is still 2*$400 for iOS and Android.

It is well known and uses mono (C#) as the scripting engine.

Comment: I know about Unity, i didn't wrote about it in my post because of the cost (as you mentioned) and because i thought everybody know it :)

Comment: It's cost is the same as for mono, which you did write though :)

Answer (score 2):

You also have the option to [compile](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aARM) mono for ARM/Android, and use it natively. It is not supported, and you have to create some wrappers around your code, so it can interface with the Android native APIs.

If using commands carefully you can then port this code with some changes to Mono for iOs and XNA (WP7) too

Comment: I didn't know! For sure i'll take it as a good option if i'll ever plan to write a game engine, but right now i "just" want to write a game, and not all the engine for it, and mono (from what i understood) is a cross platform vm for c# code. Do you know of any other game engine that uses it?

Comment: Well... Unity uses it, and WP7 is based on .NET, where games are based on XNA, which is also .NET. It is not a gaming engine though, it just can be used as one.

Answer (score 2):

[V-Play](http://v-play.net/) (v-play.net) is a cross platform 2D game engine based on Qt/QML. [API reference](http://v-play.net/doc/vplay-group.html).
It already  supports iOS, Android, Symbian, MeeGo and Desktop platforms. BlackBerry and Windows Phone support is in progress and will be added soon.
V-Play also comes with ready-to-use game templates for the most successful game genres like tower defense, platform games or puzzle games, several tutorials and demos. ([V-Play examples & demos](http://v-play.net/doc/daily/))

(Disclaimer: I'm one of the guys behind V-Play)

Answer (score 0):

I'd also suggest [GameSalad](http://gamesalad.com), it's 2D, runs on Android, iOS, and used HTML5 to support Tizen.  It's got a declarative drag-and-drop programming UI (so if you're looking for traditional text based program it's not for you).  There are many examples and tutorials online and a couple of marketplaces of templates you can use as a starting point.  Disclaimer, I'm one of the co-founders.